# Is write-only to a shared std::unordered_map thread safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Say I have an initialized but empty std::unordered_map, and two simultaneous threads that are going to populate it.  The two threads will only write to the map, and nothing will read from the map until the two threads are done.

Furthermore, the two threads will never operate on the same keys in the map.  For example, say Thread 1 will populate keys "A" through "M", and Thread 2 will simultaneously populate keys "N" through "Z".

Is this thread safe?

In my current implementation, I have 8 threads writing to a single mutexed std::unordered_map in the fashion described above.  The mutex obviously slows the process down (there are close to 10,000 keys being populated), so I'm wondering if I even need the mutex.

Thanks all!

Comment: I saw similar questions. If performance is important, consider different data structure. Perhaps having per-thread unordered_map would be the best if they don't intersect by keys.

Comment: Read up on std::unordered_map::merge. Two threads may populate two different maps then one can merge those.

Comment: @ÖöTiib That requires C++17.  The Q is tagged as C++11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not thread safe. The `std::unordered_map` class doesn't provide any special thread-safety guarantees, just the same ordinary level of thread-safety that all standard classes provide by default. That means that it is not safe for one thread to access the structure in any way while another thread is, or might be, modifying it.

Comment: IRC, there are some extra guarantees for `std` classes regarding `const` methods but they are not relevant for this case.

One simple way it can break is if inserting a new value triggers rehashing while other thread is in the middle of inserting another value.

Comment: @DanM. All `const` functions are readers, so it is fine if that is all you are doing.  As soon as you add a writer into the mix though all bets are off

Comment: @DanM. I don't like speculating about ways it can break because that leads to the (unfortunately, very common) misconception that if you can't think of a way it can break and it happens to work when you try it, then it's safe to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver no, not really. `const` functions can do anything. They are not guaranteed to be thread-safe by any margin. But STL provides that guarantee.

Comment: @DanM. I meant in the constext of the STL.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not speculating. I'm stating it as a real scenario demonstrating how it breaks thread-safety even if "all threads are acting on different keys" to reinforce the point that it's not thread-safe.

Comment: @DanM. But the problem is, if the OP has a different (but similar) question, and then concludes "I can't see how it could go wrong; it must be safe", they will have been misled.

Comment: @MartinBonner misled by what? "No, it's not safe. here is one of many ways it might break" is misleading how? I'd argue that without without this example OP might be mislead (and already almost was) "But I have a very specific use cases that surely be thread-safe!", no it's not, and here is why.

Comment: @DanM. That's a perfect example of how someone could be mislead. That you can think of a way it can fail is *NOT* why his very specific use case isn't thread-safe. His very-specific use case isn't thread-safe because the relevant standards say so. Even cases where nobody can think of a way it can fail aren't thread-safe. This is, unfortunately, a very common misconception that has led to huge amounts of pain and misery over the years.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times, usually in comments on this very web site, people insisted things were safe and I insisted they were not. Then someone (sometimes me, something not) explained a way it could fail and they said, "Oh, I see now. It's not safe." That is the worst possible lesson they could learn, setting them up to fail as soon as they rely on something whose failure modes they are not clever enough to foresee. Heck, at one time the idea that a CPU would perform writes out of program order was not foreseeable.

Comment: This is why I wanted to ask instead of locally test... not sure if my simple tests would A) work unanimously and B) be scalable to my full implementation.  Given all this information, I'm just going to just keep the mutex.  Thanks all!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and that's what I said. I never challenged the specific use case, I've added to the original question explaining it further. Because the original question was structured like so. Is A thread-safe? No. Even if I only do B? Yes, even if you only do B, here is why.

Your logic is ultimately flawed. I could argue the same thing: since the user would only get "yes/no" answers without any explanation, they'd never learn to think/foresee themselves. On the other hand, ability to challenge their ideas and quickly find counterexamples is really important.

Comment: @DanM. The thing you don't seem to get is that this particular skill of foreseeing for yourself is not only useless it is affirmatively harmful. Most of the time, you can foresee a way it can break. But it is just as wrong even when you can't foresee a way it can break, in fact, it's much more harmful then. So developing a skill to see how it could break misleads you into thinking that, in the less common case where you can't foresee a way it can break, you are safe. This is why I work hard to avoid steering people towards that way of thinking. It leads to mistakes only.